# problem creating PL/SQL procedure and sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here I have a question that I need to write a PL/SQL. The structure of the database is also linked. The question requires to use a sequence inside a procedure. I'm new to this and don't know if this works properly and my exec command doesn't seem working please help me out. Also is this how to look up the max shareholder_id that the sequence should start with, or can I a select inside create sequence?

Write a PL/SQL procedure called INSERT_DIRECT_HOLDER which will be used to insert new direct holders.  Create a sequence to automatically generate shareholder_ids.  Use this sequence in your procedure.
-Input parameters: first_name, last_name

```
DROP SEQUENCE shareholder_id_seq;

SELECT 
    MAX(shareholder_id)
FROM shareholder;

CREATE SEQUENCE shareholder_id_seq
   INCREMENT BY 1
   START WITH 25;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_direct_holder(
    p_first_name in direct_holder.first_name%type,
    p_last_name in direct_holder.last_name%type)
IS  
    v_shareholder_id NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DIRECT_HOLDER(direct_holder_id,first_name,last_name) values(shareholder_id_seq.nextval, p_first_name, p_last_name);
  INSERT INTO shareholder (shareholder_id, type) VALUES (shareholder_id_seq.nextval,'Direct_Holder');
  COMMIT;
  END;
  /
/* test command*/
exec insert_direct_holder( p_first_name, p_last_name );
```

[image]

Comment: Two questions:
1. Has your procedure compiled successfully?
2. Your second INSERT statement says shareholder_id_seq.nextval. Want to make sure if that's what you want or do you want to use the same value as in the upper INSERT statement - shareholder_id_seq.currval?

Comment: When you execute the procedure, you need to pass actual values for the firstname and lastname parameters, e.g. `insert_direct_holder('Jessica', 'Jones')`.

Comment: Yes, the procedure compiled successfully. And yes, because direct_holder is a type of shareholder so I guess I need to insert into both shareholder and direct_holder right? Although the question did not specify.

Comment: You're generating separate sequence numbers for two tables instead of using same sequence number ,first store sequence number into the variable and use that variable in both tables

Comment: Thank you @WilliamRobertson I guess the program works fine, I forgot to add single quotation mark when passing in values. In terms of the create sequence block, everytime I run the procedure I need to run the sequence first and hard code the number in start with?

Comment: @JiaqiYuan, as per your ERD, there are two tables - ShareHolder (PK - shareholder_id) and Direct_ShareHolder  (PK, FK - direct_holder_id). 
Does direct_holder_id (FK) point to shareholder_id (PK)in ShareHolder table?
If yes, then you may want to use the same value by using seq_name.currval.

Comment: You don't create the sequence object every time. Create it once and it will stay in the database, proving new sequential numbers whenever you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the record with same ID in both the tables.
also, you need to insert record into your parent table (shareholder) first and then child table(direct_holder).

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_direct_holder(
        p_first_name in direct_holder.first_name%type,
        p_last_name in direct_holder.last_name%type)
    IS  
        v_shareholder_id NUMBER(6);
    BEGIN
      v_shareholder_id := shareholder_id_seq.nextval;
      
      INSERT INTO shareholder (shareholder_id, type) VALUES (v_shareholder_id,'Direct_Holder');

      INSERT INTO DIRECT_HOLDER(direct_holder_id,first_name,last_name) values(v_shareholder_id, p_first_name, p_last_name);
      COMMIT;
    END;
    /

/* test command*/
exec insert_direct_holder( p_first_name, p_last_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequence is created once to implement auto incrementing feature for any numeric column.
For the current use case it has to be created just once and left forever hopefully.Sequence can be modified in future if required.

If shareholder table has records in it already, then create the sequence with start value as `SELECT MAX(shareholder_id) + 1 FROM shareholder;` to avoid primary key constraint violation.

A slight modification is required for the stored procedure to use the same `SHAREHOLDER.SHAREHOLDER_ID` as the column has foreign key relationship with `DIRECT_HOLDER`.

Use `INSERT ALL` to insert to both the tables for the same sequence.nextval.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_direct_holder(
        p_first_name in direct_holder.first_name%type,
        p_last_name in direct_holder.last_name%type)
    IS  

 BEGIN

 INSERT ALL
 INTO SHAREHOLDER
  (shareholder_id, type) values(shareholder_id_seq.nextval,'Direct_Holder')
 INTO DIRECT_HOLDER
  (direct_holder_id,first_name,last_name) values 
 (shareholder_id_seq.nextval,p_first_name,p_last_name)
 SELECT 'DUMMY' FROM dual;

 COMMIT;
     
 END;
 /
```

dbfiddle demo with working code : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d80488fb69d78d4b5087f06a5becf96

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvoting,happy to help/provide alternate solution. Updating the solution with more details and dbfiddle demo in case if you couldn't make it work yet.Downvoting without any reason wouldn't help the community in anyway.